# How many Starship launches would it take to build this simple centrifugal space station concept?

Tags: launch, spacecraft, design-alternative

Every centrifugal space station design I have seen uses either a large curved material or an inflatable structure. There have been no large scale curved material construction in space and only [one experiment on inflatable structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflatable_space_habitat#Ongoing_research) conducted.

One thing we can do on a regular basis is launch straight tubes into space and connect them together - its what [the ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station) is built of - so what if we design our centrifugal space station around this limitation?

Looking at the minimum number of tubes would yield a design like so:

[image: centrifugal concept]

There wouldn't be a center point that doesn't move so it would take some aiming to dock properly, but that's a problem for a computer. You move from one tube to another by connecting the ends of 2 tubes together - something we can do with docking ports already.

If you consider a much larger budget then you could do a design like this and be able to take advantage of the entire simulated "gravity gradient" in a beautiful "Peter Pan'd Pepperoni Pizza":

[image: centrifugal concept]

So if you are in a tube that is 1/3 of the way from the center, then you are simulating Mars gravity, if you are in a tube on the outside you are simulating earth gravity. You can even keep building out past earth gravity so that you could simulate gravity greater than earth! And you don't have to wait until it is finished to put it to work.

But thinking practically, how many Starships, or similar sized craft, would it take to make the circumference needed to produce artificial gravity?

(i understand that cylinders are weakest with forces applied in these directions ie i can stand on a soda can but if i stand on its side i will crush it, so maybe triangle tubes would be the best shape?)

Comment: Material & estimated volume? Earth launches are limited by payload size ~4.5 m and mass envelope.

Comment: So the size would be the smallest possible, where you can walk around without getting sick, right? And maybe  hexagonal tubes would be advantageous.

Comment: It depends on the rotational speed of your station

Comment: The question cannot be answered as written. Spin gravity is driven by radius and rotation rate so a single starship can generate one G at high RPM. If you want a saner rotation speed you fly two and a long cable. Suggest you change question to be either 'is this pizza design good' with some measure of good, or 'how many Starship flights to lift an example ring station'.

Comment: The point about straight tubes being easier to ground assemble and launch than curved station segments. For a reasonably well worked example, see https://gatewayspaceport.com/von-braun-station/

Comment: @mothman it would be made out of starships or whatever spacecraft you are launching. The point is you don’t have to manufacture anything new, just launch existing tech and attach it together in orbit

Comment: @GremlinWranger the von Braun one has curved metal segments and a large steel support structure. Both things we have not done in space. They also have their habitation tubes mounted as if you wrapped a string of sausages around a bicycle tire whereas mine is like putting sausages next to each other on the tire, like how the fingers on your hand are mounted. From there it should be easy to calculate what circumference of station you need and how many ship diameters would fit in that

Comment: @Antzi it would be the rotation needed to attain artificial gravity assuming you attached a string of ships together as pictured

Comment: @SpaceBread yes exactly. Whatever it would take to make it work

Comment: @user1886419 the rotation speed will depend on the number of ships, and vice versa

Comment: @GremlinWranger the station would be made of starships. If the starships were on the ground ready to launch, the diagrams pictured would be a top down view like a street map

Comment: @Antzi yes and given we know the diameter of a ship the rest can be calculated from there

Comment: Do you mean you want a 16 cylinders station ?

Comment: @Antzi the number of cylinders is what I am curious about. Pick a craft. Any craft. How many would it take?

Comment: If you want 1G acceleration; the rotational speed will depend on the diameter (which is to say the number of cylinders). So there are two unknown: the number of cylinders AND the rotational speed. Without either of this informations we cannot solve the equation ...

Comment: @Antzi I assumed this was a static calculation done years ago. That is to say we know the minimum diameter and minimum rotational speed to get this done. So I guess there is no existing spec to build to?No equation you could plug stuff in to figure this out? Where did the the designers of the other existing centrifugal space station designs, like von braun, start to come up with their dimensions?Or even Kubrick for 2001? Is this an unknown and people are just making cool designs without dimensions?Is this why we don’t know how to build these because we are still unsure of the proper dimensions

Comment: You don’t get jt. The acceleration (g) is proportional to diameter and rotation speed. Big diameter => low speed small diameter => high speed. There is no answer because every answer is correct.

Comment: @Antzi so I only need to launch one starship and get it spinning like a log at the correct speed? Why don’t we do this today? Seems cheap

Comment: @user1886419 yes, you can simulate 1G with only one spinning starship.  We don’t do it because the purpose of sending humans to space is to have 0G. There are others answers that explain it

Comment: @Antzi isn't the issue with doing it with one that the gravity gradient from your head to toe would be to large and thus make you sick, so they have found an ideal size that gives you a more manageable gravity gradient from head to toe, that size is what i am asking about

Comment: Then you should ask what is the minimum comfortable size for a spinning station. The answer will probably be something like "we don't know because we never flew one before"